# Finding path and creating a file in c# windows automatically

Tags: c#, winforms

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly
                      .GetExecutingAssembly().Location + 
                           @"\keyfile\EmailbodyorFile.txt");
```

I used this to get the path,but my problem is 'EmailbodyorFile.txt' must be created automatically during run-time and the above code do not create the file.So what to do?

Earlier I used this code ,

```
string path = Path.GetFullPath(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +
@"\keyfile\EmailbodyorFile.txt");
```

and it run correctly,but after creating setup of project, it shows error 'File not found error'.

please help.

Comment: How would it magically create a file if you have not written a code for it? You need to use File class. Use File.Exists method to check if file exists in same location, if not Create it.

Comment: you should check is directory exist, if it's not - create by Directory.Create(...), when check is file exist, if it's not - create by File.Create(...)

Comment: Is this a Windows Form or a WPF Application?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Check for existence of file
string filePath=System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\keyfile\EmailbodyorFile.txt"  
if(!File.Exists(filePath) 
{
    //If not existing then create it       
    File.Create(filePath); 
}
using (StreamWriter FileWriter= File.AppendText(filePath)))
{
    FileWriter.WriteLine("Your Content string");              
}
```

Comment: When i tried to create gives error,Could not find a part of the path 'F:\Encryptingmail\OurEnctyption\bin\Debug\OurEnctyption.exe\keyfile\EmailbodyorFile.txt'.

Comment: That means the path you have given is not a valid path to create a file, i have updated the answer, please check it\

Comment: Btw `File.AppendText` will create the file if it doesn't exist, so checking for its existence is not necessary here.

Comment: @vesan: Checking necessary here, we should omit else; hence if the file is existing then append the text to it, else we create the file and write text to it. anyway thanks for the point

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath),
                    @"\keyfile\EmailbodyorFile.txt");
Directory.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\KeyFile";
string file = "EmailbodyorFile.txt";

if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

**Open if exists or Create if not**

```
System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path + "\\" + file, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
```

**You Can Read Like**

```
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fs);
string fileContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
```

**Or Can Write Like**

```
System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs);
string writeToFile = "I want to add this to my newly created file";
sw.Write(writeToFile);
```